# Clearing the Gridview in c#

Tags: c#

I am making my C# project and I want to clear the Gridview but the main purpose is after the Gridview is cleared, only a new data inserted should be seen however the old data is saved in my database.I was able to clear my Gridview but after inserting new data my old data is also shown in that gridview which should not be seen.Will be thankful for your suggestions.

Comment: Keep track of the last saved ID, and then as new stuff comes in the new IDs will be bigger... until you hit save again

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: So you clear the data and insert exactly the same data.....?

Comment: How are you getting the new data from the database? Once the gridView is cleared all you have to do is make sure that only new data is retreived from the database or at least inserted in the gridView.

Comment: this seems like something that should be filtered out when retrieving the data.  Can you add some code of how you retrieve the data from your database?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Thanks @BugFinder My problem sloved by keeping track.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that in most cases the DataGrid is bound to a DataSet. You could simply exchange the DataSet with a different one. Or maybe you modify the contents of the original DataSet, but in this case you would maybe need to cut the connection to the database if you don't want the data getting persisted...